# Filter query result by multiple entries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access DB with a table Table1 which contains the following information:

```
ADDRESS_ID | CATEGORY_ID
1          | 12
2          | 41
2          | 66
3          | 41
4          | 41
4          | 66
```

Each ADDRESS_ID belongs to a dedicated customer (uniquely assigned).

I need to create an SQL query which returns only those rows of the table for which the ADDRESS_ID has exactly ONE dedicated entry, e.g. if my filter criteria is "Return CATEGORY_ID=41", the expected result is:

```
ADDRESS_ID | CATEGORY_ID
3          | 41
```

or if it is "Return CATEGORY_ID=66", the result is an empty table.

How can I implement a query without performing postprocessing by script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select address_id
from table1
group by address_id
having min(category_id) = max(category_id) and
       min(category_id) = 41;
```

You can add `41 as category_id` to the `select` if you want but you already know that.

If there are no duplicate pairs in the table, you can also phrase this as:

```
select address_id
from table1
group by address_id
having count(*) = 1 and
       min(category_id) = 41;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `count()` and `having`:

```
SELECT
    ADDRESS_ID,
    CATEGORY_ID
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    CATEGORY_ID=41
GROUP BY
    ADDRESS_ID,
    CATEGORY_ID
HAVING
    Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
select t.*
from table as t
where CATEGORY_ID = 66 and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from table as t1 
                  where t1.ADDRESS_ID = t.ADDRESS_ID and t1.CATEGORY_ID <> t.CATEGORY_ID
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select address_id, max(category_id) category_id
from tablename
group by address_id
having min(category_id) = max(category_id)
```

returns:

> only those rows of the table for which the ADDRESS_ID has exactly ONE
>   dedicated entry

Now you can apply any filter to it and get the results you want:

```
select t.* from (
    select address_id, max(category_id) category_id
    from tablename
    group by address_id
    having min(category_id) = max(category_id)
) t
where t.category_id = 41
```